# Random Movement Script causes Unity to freeze

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a grid consisting of 16 tiles. Now basically I want the user to find a path to the final location by moving randomly on the choices he has within the grid.

As of now I managed to create the functions for moving a step up, down, left and right. The issue arises when I'm trying to code in random movement. Ideally this is setup in a way that he can't go off bounds from the grid.

This is what I got going:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Move : MonoBehaviour

{
    void Up()
    {
        //get the Input from Horizontal axis
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //get the Input from Vertical axis
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1.5f, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }

    void Down()
    {
        //get the Input from Horizontal axis
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //get the Input from Vertical axis
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -1.5f, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }

    void Left()
    {
        //get the Input from Horizontal axis
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //get the Input from Vertical axis
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-1.5f, 0, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }

    void Right()
    {
        //get the Input from Horizontal axis
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        //get the Input from Vertical axis
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }



    void Start()
    {
        var finalLocation = new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
        var currentLocation = transform.position;

        while (currentLocation != finalLocation)
        {
            int randomNum = Random.Range(0, 3);

            if (randomNum == 0)
            {
                Up();
            }
            else if (randomNum == 1)
            {
                Down();
            }
            else if (randomNum == 2)
            {
                Left();
            }
            else if (randomNum == 3)
            {
                Right();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED WORKING CODE:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Move : MonoBehaviour

{
    void Up()
    {
        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1.5f, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }

    void Down()
    {
        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, -1.5f, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }

    void Left()
    {
        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-1.5f, 0, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }

    void Right()
    {
        //update the position
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(1.5f, 0, 0);

        //output to log the position change
        Debug.Log(transform.position);
    }



    void Update()
    {
        var finalLocation = new Vector3(2.5f, 2.0f, -2.0f);
        var currentLocation = transform.position; 
        int randomNum = Random.Range(0, 4);

        if (currentLocation != finalLocation) { 
                if (randomNum == 0)
            {
                Up();
            }
            else if (randomNum == 1)
            {
                Down();
            }
            else if (randomNum == 2)
            {
                Left();
            }
            else if (randomNum == 3)
            {
                Right();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My last issue is how I can limit this randomness to only stick to the grid and not go off grid. Any thoughts?

Comment: There might be a problem in the while and the current location might always be different to the final location so the script gets engaged in an endless loop

Comment: Also, why are you querying `Input`?

Comment: @3Dave whats the use?

Answer (score 1):

Several problems:

1. Your object is stuck in an endless `while` loop because it isn't allowed to exit (and do things like render the frame, take input from the user, etc) until your random movement script reaches its `finalLocation`. You aren't giving the game *time* to do anything else.
   You almost certainly want this to be a coroutine or an `Update` function.
2. [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) returns an int in the range `min` (inclusive) to `max` (exclusive), so your call to it will never return `3`.

Comment: `Random.Range` with `int` values as parameters returns an `int` value, though. The second parameter is exclusive so `Random.Range(0,3)` can return any of the values `0, 1, 2` .. so it will surely **never** return `3`

Comment: You're right, I saw only the first one with the float parameters earlier.

Comment: Hi @Draco18s thanks for the input. I took your advice and implemented the changes however with the Update function is still crashes.

Comment: @xalalau how did you do it? There shouldn't be a `while` loop at all!

Comment: @derHugo I managed to make it work thanks. See above code. One issue maybe someone may guide me in the right direction is I want the 'User' to be able to move within the grid and not go off grid like it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some problems:

- `horizontalInput` and `verticalInput` are never used inside your functions
- `while(currentLocation != finalLocation)` This condition can fail in some situations. Unity uses *float* for the coordinates, meaning it needs to be exactly on the same position, every decimal place need to be the same.
- `Random.Range(0, 3)` will return a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 3 (exclusive), so the only possible values will be 0, 1 and 2. The script will never call the `Right()` function.

Unity uses one thread to run your scripts by default, if you put a while loop to move the object to a location it will freeze the entire game till the object is at the proper place. I recommend you to use the `Update()` function, it gets called every frame.

Comment: `every decimal place need to be the same.` that's not entirely true: The [`==` operator for `Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) uses a precision of `0.00001` for equality. When moving the object in fixed steps it is at least not completely impossible to reach a certain position here (ofcourse you're right and in general the code doesn't make a lot of sense)

Comment: you probably do not want to call this in `Update` either.. moving every frame to a new position in steps of `1.5` units will create a huge jittery movement.

Comment: Yeah, he needs to multiply by Time.deltaTime and the input value, but that is not the problem.

Comment: Hi @BlackDereker thanks for the input. I took your advice and implemented the changes however with the Update function is still crashes. What do you mean with time.deltatime? Thanks!

Comment: You need to get rid of the `while` loop and replace it with an `if`